# Why is VS Code calling both source miniconda3/bin/activate and conda activate in fish shell?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, fish

When I open a terminal in VS Code with the automatic environment activation the following happens:

```
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
luka@Lukas-MBP ~/D/e/p/collatz-conjecture> source /Users/luka/miniconda3/bin/activate                                                                                    (base) 
~/miniconda3/bin/activate (line 5): 'return' outside of function definition
\. "$_CONDA_ROOT/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" || return $?
                                            ^
from sourcing file ~/miniconda3/bin/activate
        called on standard input

source: Error while reading file '/Users/luka/miniconda3/bin/activate'
luka@Lukas-MBP ~/D/e/p/collatz-conjecture> conda activate base                                                                                                           (base)
```

How can I prevent VS Code from calling both commands and only using `conda activate base`, while still using automatic environment activation feature.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using a version of conda older than 4.6 where I don't think there was fish support. Update to 4.6 or newer and use `conda init` to set up your shell configuration files and that should solve the problem.

Comment: That bug says it should be using `.` instead of `source`, which is wrong. Fish ships a `.` function for compatibility, but `source` is a builtin. At best it'll do the exact same thing. So that can't be it.

Comment: @faho you're right, it's because fish wasn't appropriately supported when we added support for conda and so we were doing it the "old" way of conda 4.5 of sourcing the conda.sh file which only works for bash. I've updated my reply.